# Opening a file in an existing Qt creator instance

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

My team is working with QT creator 2.8.0 to develop our product on Linux Suse 11.
I'm developing an external tool to help with managing source-control (git-flow) and dev tasks and schedule.

I can use my tool to open files in QT creator from command line, but I much prefer telling the existing instance of QT creator to open them. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simple command:

```
<path_to>/qtcreator -client <file_path>
```

You can do:

```
<path_to>/qtcreator -help
```

to see all the other command line options the creator provides

Comment: Thanks. That's great!!!  Once the file is open is there any thing that the command line can do? for instance focus on a row?

Comment: Yes. You can read more about it here: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cli.html